# How can I assert in a unit test that a regex pattern occurs multiple times in a string?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-re

I have a unit test that asserts that a certain regex pattern appears in a multiline string:

```py
import unittest

class TestStrRegex(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_pattern_matches_thrice(self):
        string = """\
        repeatedval=78
        badval=89
        # comment
        repeatedval=20
        repeatedval=8978
        """
        self.assertRegex(string, 'repeatedval=\d+')
```

I would like to assert that the `'repeatedval=\d+'` pattern matches exactly three times in the string, something like this:

```py
self.assertRegex(string, 'repeatedval=\d+', exact_number_of_matches=3)
```

But that doesn't work. Is there another way to make this assertion?

Comment: You have 2 solutions, one is to stick with `assertRegex`. in this case update the regex itself to check the desired string 3 times. Other way is to use `assertEqual` and make sure the regex is present in the string exactly 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `re` module directly, and assert that the result has a particular length.

```
def test_pattern_matches_thrice(self):
    string = """..."""
    result = re.findall(r'repeatedval=\d+', string)
    self.assertEqual(len(result), 3)
```